# How to merge two lines ending at a certain character in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How can I merge two lines if the line finishes with a certain text or character (e.g., `$`)?

For example how can I go from

```
LU039F1R 5298.329, 239.725, 769.615, $
    -0.17307, -0.01813, 0.98474
LU039G1L 5309.644, -240.726, 762.655, $
    0.99595, -0.07970, -0.04152
```

to

```
LU039F1R 5298.329, 239.725, 769.615, -0.17307, -0.01813, 0.98474
LU039G1L 5309.644, -240.726, 762.655,0.99595, -0.07970, -0.04152
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\$\s*`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\$      : $ character, it have to be escaped because it's a special character
\s*     : 0 or more space character, including line break
```

**Result for given example:**

```
LU039F1R 5298.329, 239.725, 769.615, -0.17307, -0.01813, 0.98474
LU039G1L 5309.644, -240.726, 762.655, 0.99595, -0.07970, -0.04152
```

Comment: @ManishChaudhry: You're welcome, glad it helps.